# Redirecting from http to https fails partly

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, handlebars.js

I used this code-snippet, to forward every `http-request` to `https-request`:

```
 app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
 if (req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] != 'https') {

     res.redirect(req.connection.remoteAddress);
 }
 else {
     next();
 }
 })
```

If you type `example.com` it will go to `https://example.com/` that's fine.

But if you type it `http://example.com/someparam` goes to `http://example.com/::ffff:10.45.53.139`.

That is strange, because if you type `https://example.com/someparam` straight into your browser it works.

From the backend I get the code from `xyz.herokuapp.com`, but if I type `xyz.herokuapp.com` it also gets a strange result `http://xyz.herokuapp.com/::ffff:10.45.79.55`.

But using this `https://xyz.herokuapp.com/` works...

It seems to redirect twice right ?!

Comment: `req.connection.remoteAddress` should contain the clients address, are you sure that's what you want?  Should you be redirecting to the sites address? using https protocol?

Comment: I would like to force the https, so if someone visits "xyz.herokuapp.com" or "example.com" it should automatically force https...

Answer (score 0):

I think that `req.connection.remoteAddress` is referring to the IP address where the request is coming from - so you wouldn't want to redirect back to that. I assume you would want to redirect to your own  domain using https while preserving the path. This should redirect and preserve the path:

```
if(req.headers['x-forwarded-proto'] !== 'https') {
    return res.redirect('https://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl);
}
```

Comment: If I do it like that ´res.redirect('https://' + req.get('xyz.herokuapp.com') + req.originalUrl);´ and type in that ´http://example.com/someparam´ it redirects me to a search engine.

Comment: Why are you doing `req.get('xyz.herokuapp.com')`? My example uses `req.get('host')`. Use it exactly how I have it in my example.